# NotBlank not found in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I am novice in Symfony2.

When i use

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint\NotBlank;
```

it gives error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint\NotBlank' not found in /var/www/Symfony/src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Enquiry.php on line 19
```

Please suggest how to add NotBlank constraint inside symfony, as I checked Symfony's documentation, but i didn't understand a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint\NotBlank` should be `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank`.